# How to set up Asus RT-N66U in bridge mode with wired connection to main router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I have a wired router (TP-Link RT-860) in the basement where the cable service comes in. Eight wired ethernet connections span two buildings. I currently have a Linksys wireless router set up in bridge mode, but its signal doesn't span the whole area. I have purchased an Asus RT-N66U to replace it, but I can't figure out how to set it up in bridge mode. Does anyone know if this is possible? Second question: Would there be any advantage in installing DD-WRT on the Asus?

Comment: I suggest only asking one question at a time.

Answer (score 7):

Click *Administration* in the left menu and select *Access Point(AP) mode*:

> In Access Point (AP) mode, RT-N66U connects to a wireless router through an Ethernet cable to extend the wireless signal coverage to other network clients. In this mode, the firewall, IP sharing, and NAT functions are disabled by default.

...and of course press the *Save* button.